# No aparece Plantilla MVC5 Visual Studio 2013

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5

Instale el vs2013 ultimate, update 1, update 5, pack lenguaje ingles, web developper tools.... Y sigue sin aparecer la plantilla MVC cuando selecciono en C# ASP.NET

[image: plantilla mvc 1]

[image: plantilla mvc 2]

Comment: click en Visual Studio 2012 que tienes abierto?

Comment: en Visual Studio 2012 solo aparece mvc4

Comment: Suena típico pero... has probado a reiniciar? xD

Comment: Si, ya reinicie toda la PC y no pasa nada :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

la solución fue reinstalar el vs... instale la versión Express para Web.